# Lookup next column if lookup value begins with certain string

Tags: excel, match

I am trying to match a value in an array. If the lookup value begins with any value in the table then it will return the value in the next column. The problem is that each value in Column A is of different length.

Is it still possible to match it in Excel without using VBA?

[image: SO53941652 Q example]

Answer (score 0):

Try looking up the "most demanding" string first (most characters) and if not found (ie an error), look up progressively shorter strings, eg:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(D3,4),A:B,2,0),VLOOKUP(LEFT(D3,3),A:B,2,0))
```

[image: SO53941652 example]

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have thought of using the LEFT function but I would also like to have some flexibility so that I can add few more rows in column A with different length. Sorry that I didn't make it clear!